# How to check an object's type in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, types, detection

Is there a simple way to check the type of an object? I need something along the following lines:

```
MyObject^ mo = gcnew MyObject();
Object^ o = mo;

if( o->GetType() == MyObject )
{
    // Do somethine with the object
}
else
{
    // Try something else
}
```

At the moment I'm using nested try-catch blocks looking for `System::InvalidCastException`s which feels ugly but works. I was going to try and profile something like the code above to see if it's any faster/slower/readable but can't work out the syntax to even try.

In case anyone's wondering, this comes from having a single queue entering a thread which supplied data to work on. Occasionally I want to change settings and passing them in via the data queue is a simple way of doing so.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `MyObject::typeid` in C++/CLI the same way as `typeof(MyObject)` is used in C#. Code below shamelessly copied from your question and modified ...

```
MyObject^ mo = gcnew MyObject();
Object^ o = mo;

if( o->GetType() == MyObject::typeid )
{
    // Do somethine with the object
}
else
{
    // Try something else
}
```

Comment: It still works in VS2010. I don't have VS2012 so can't comment on the latest VS version. It may be you are not "seeing that typeid member" because autocomplete for C++/CLI was not included in VS2010.

Comment: I could even use it in VS2013.

Answer (score 10):

You should check out [How to: Implement is and as C# Keywords in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85af44e9.aspx):

> This topic shows how to implement the functionality of the is and as C# keywords in Visual C++.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with generics rather than templates so that the method can be used in external assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** I will leave this here. But this answer is for C++. Probably not even slightly related to doing this for the CLI.

You need to compile with RTTI(Run Time Type Information) on.  Then look at the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information and search google for RTTI.   Should work for you.

On the other hand you might want to have a virtual base class for all your data classes with a member variable that describes what type it is.