# Single C++/CLI method to wrap many type specific C functions

Tags: c#, c, c++-cli

I am wrapping a C library using C++/CLI so that the C library can be used easily from C# in a C#'ish way.

Some of the functions in this library are for putting a value into a container. There are no generics in C so there exists a function per type   CLIB_SetBool(BOOL value), CLIB_SetInt(int value), CLIB_SetString(char* string) and so on.

To make it easier to use from C#, I have created a single Set function which takes a System::Object.

I have two related questions:

1. With my method how would you use a switch statement on the type of System::Object to call the correct CLIB_Setxxxx  function.   [typeid is only for unmanaged code and I can't seem to use GetType.]
2. Is there a better way to wrap these functions like using a Generic?  [I started using template specialisation but then realised that C# doesn't see templates.]

Thanks.

**EDIT**

How do I implement void Set(System::Object^ value) ?

I want to do something like:

```
void MyWrapper::Set(System::Object^ value)
{
 switch(typeid(value))
  {
   case System::Int32:  CLIB_SetInt(MyMarshal<clib_int>(value));    break;
   case System::Double: CLIB_SetInt(MyMarshal<clib_double>(value)); break;
//and so on
}
}
```

The typeid fails for managed code and clearly the cases are invalid. How to fix?

Comment: Won't a simple overload do ?

Comment: I agree with Alexandre; the safest and most transparent way to do this is to simply write one wrapper per function call as a set of overloads.

Comment: From C# I will want to put a System::Object (I'm using a devexpress container) so one of my overloads will be Set(System::Object^ value) and it is this function that I don't know how (syntax) to implement. +1 to Alexandre C

Comment: Agree three.  It's also quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't use a switch because there doesn't seem to be an integral representation of type for managed code as there is in C++.

The following works.

```
void MyWrapper::Set(System::Object^ value)
{
  if (value->GetType() == System::Int32::typeid)
  {
      CLIB_SetInt(MyMarshal<clib_int>(value));
  }  
  else if ((value->GetType() == System::Double::typeid)
  {
      CLIB_SetDouble(MyMarshal<clib_double>(value));
  }
//etc
}
```

Comment: +1: Was just scanning the responses before providing my own answer and this is how I would have done it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do worse than utilize a dictionary of delegates, keyed by type (Sorry for C# syntax, it's been a while since I did C++/CLI).  Within each delegate, of course, you make your actual call to the appropriate C function.

```
public delegate void CLIBDelegate(object);


// handlers for types that will call the appropriate CLIB_XXX function:
public void CLIB_int(object _obj);
public void CLIB_string(object _obj);
// etc...


// Our dictionary:
Dictionary<System.Type, CLIBDelegate> dict = new Dictionary<System.Type, CLIBDelegate>();
dict[typeof(System.Int32)] = CLIB_int;
dict[typeof(System.string] = CLIB_string;
// etc...


// your set function
void Set(Object _object)
{
    if(dict.ContainsKey(_object.GetType())
        dict[_object.GetType()](_object);
} // eo Set
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am really looking for a C++/CLI solution which where the lookup is done statically (for better performance). I am just bogged down on how to compare the type of System::Object against all supported types in the case statements.

Comment: @T33C: `if (o is int) ... else if (o is string) else ...`

Comment: @leppie, I have omitted the actual call to the C function.  At some point, whatever method he uses, he's going to have to convert the managed type to unmanaged, right?

Comment: @moo-juice: yes, unless there is some other form of magic that could work, like creating generic wrappers on the fly with conversions.

Comment: @moo-juice: Actually, what you said, could well work, given you call the correct method from within the 'generic' one (with object param). I dont really see much of a problem. Also, just call the delegate directly, and not using Invoke, eg: `dict[_object.GetType()](_object)`. (+1 after clarification, you may want to add that to your answer)

Comment: @leppie  I have marshalling. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: If your parameter is of type object, which means the actual type is known at runtime only, how could anyone do a static lookup?

Comment: Because the types of the cases with which I want to compare are static.  switch(variable) case static:

Answer (score 2):

What about some overloads as follows..

```
ref class CLIB_Wrapper
{
    static void Set(System::Boolean^ value) { CLIB_SetBool(*value); }
    static void Set(System::Int32^ value) { CLIB_SetInt(*value); }
    static void Set(System::String^ value) { CLIB_SetString(*value); }

    static void Set(System::Object^ value)
    {
        System::Type^ type = value->GetType();
        if( type == System::Boolean::typeid )
        {
            Set((System::Boolean^)value);
        }
        else if( type == System::Int32::typeid )
        {
            Set((System::Int32^)value);
        }
        else if( type == System::String::typeid )
        {
            Set((System::String^)value);
        }
    }
};
```

Obviously you'll need some conversions in there with appropriate marshalling for the String -> char* conversion, but you get the idea.

**Edited to include detection of type**

Comment: +1  but what about static void CLIB_Set(System::Object value) {...} ?

Comment: You can detect the type in the same way that I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410721/how-to-check-an-objects-type-in-c-cli